# Creating a custom firebase data message handler vue that replies to originating app on push notification

Tags: firebase, vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli-3

I have a Vue app that is linked to Firebase messaging service. Firebase uses a service worker to handle the push notifications. The service worker is registered by the vue CLI 3.  When a firebase data message push notification gets received by the service worker, I want a postMessage to be triggered back to the app.
The message handler looks as follows:

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  client.postMessage({      // ERR: client unknown
        msg: "Data message recieved"
      })

  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title'
  const notificationOptions = {
     body: 'Background Message body.',
     icon: 'img/i_icon_96.png'
   }
   return self.registration.showNotification(
     notificationTitle,
     notificationOptions
   )
}
```

I do not know how to get the client. It seems to be a problem with how Vue CLI registers the service worker and that the clients are not set.

When I register the service worker in the main.js I get two service workers and a client, but I allso get a un-ending loop, so I know it must be possible.

How do I get the vue cli to register the client in the service worker? 
or how do I get the service worker to get the relevant client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code only needed a ping to refresh variables once a notification was send to the firebase service worker.

The main fault I was making is to try and test it in the dev environment. I had to to deploy the final code onto a https server to get it to work.

My entire firebase-messaging-sw.js looks like this:

```
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.2/firebase-messaging.js')

const firebase_config = {
  apiKey: '{your api key}',
  projectId: '{your product id}',
  messagingSenderId: '{your sender id}',
  appId: '{your appid}'
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config)

// not needed
const messaging = firebase.messaging()
console.log('Token', messaging.getToken())
// not needed
```

in the main.js I initiated the app as follow:

```
const firebase_config = {
  apiKey: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APIKEY},
  authDomain: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN},
  databaseURL: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL},
  projectId: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID},
  storageBucket: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET},
  messagingSenderId: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID},
  appId: {VUE_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID}
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebase_config)

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
  console.log('Push Notification Recieved') // refresh code goes here  
})
```

The addEventListener was enough, I did not need the different custom messenger handlers.